# VS2017 15.7.3 C++ Document Format reorders lines and causes compile errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

After I upgrade my VS2017 to the latest version (15.7.3), Document Format for C++ (Ctrl+K,Ctrl+D) will reorder all included file lines, and it also reformat other code to cause many compiling errors. Right now I have to use a diff tool to double-check code and reverse unwanted changes.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Select only the text to be formatted and select `Format Selected` from Menu/Edit/Advanced or (Ctrl+K,Ctrl+F)

Comment: _"it also reformat other code to cause many compiling errors"_ What reformats? What errors?

Comment: @seccpurs Often I have to reformat a complete file which is very poorly formatted, unfortunately.

Comment: @underscore_d Errors are because of running Document Format. Code itself is fine, just very poorly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after searching around the net, it looks like recent vs2017 added ClangFormat support. The default settings messed up my code. Here is vs2017 blog:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/03/13/clangformat-support-in-visual-studio-2017-15-7-preview-1/

Skimming through the ClangFormat document: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html, the code style and formatting features can be customized. Since I'm new to this, I have turned it off for the time being (Tools/Options -> TextEditor->C/C++->Formatting->General->Enable ClangFormat support).